# Why can´t I walk while crouching?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

So, apperently I am trying to make a game using unity.
So far so good.
But there is one problem: Everytime I crouch or slide, I cant move anymore until I stand up again.
I ve tried everything.
I ve even tried removing the sliding completely or writing a whole new code, yet nothing works.
Sorry for the long code, but I dont know anymore ;-;

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

//Assingables
public Transform playerCam;
public Transform orientation;

//Other
private Rigidbody rb;

//Rotation and look
private float xRotation;
private float sensitivity = 50f;
public float sensMultiplier = 1f;

//Movement
public float moveSpeed = 4500;
public float maxSpeed = 10;
public bool grounded;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;

public float counterMovement = 0.175f;
private float threshold = 0.01f;
public float maxSlopeAngle = 35f;

public float sprintspeed = 20f;
public float speedOrigin = 10f;




//Crouch & Slide
private Vector3 crouchScale = new Vector3(1, 0.5f, 1);
private Vector3 playerScale;
public float slideForce = 0;
public float slideCounterMovement = 0.2f;

//Jumping
private bool readyToJump = true;
private float jumpCooldown = 0.25f;
public float jumpForce = 300f;

//Input
float x, y;
bool jumping, sprinting, crouching;

//Sliding
private Vector3 normalVector = Vector3.up;
private Vector3 wallNormalVector;

void Awake() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Start() {
    playerScale =  transform.localScale;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}


private void FixedUpdate() {
    Movement();
}

private void Update() {
    MyInput();
    Look();
}

/// <summary>
/// Find user input. Should put this in its own class but im lazy
/// </summary>
private void MyInput() {
    x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    jumping = Input.GetButton("Jump");
    crouching = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);

   
    //Sprinting
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && !crouching)
        StartSprint();
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        StopSprint();


    //Crouching
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        StartCrouch();
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        StopCrouch();
}

private void StartCrouch() {
    transform.localScale = crouchScale;
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.5f, transform.position.z);
    maxSpeed = 7f;
}

private void StopCrouch() {
    transform.localScale = playerScale;
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z);
    maxSpeed = speedOrigin;
}

//Sprinting
private void StartSprint() {
    maxSpeed = sprintspeed;
}
private void StopSprint() {
    maxSpeed = speedOrigin;
}
    

private void Movement() {
    //Extra gravity
    rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 10);
    
    //Find actual velocity relative to where player is looking
    Vector2 mag = FindVelRelativeToLook();
    float xMag = mag.x, yMag = mag.y;

    //Counteract sliding and sloppy movement
    CounterMovement(x, y, mag);
    
    //If holding jump && ready to jump, then jump
    if (readyToJump && jumping) Jump();

    //Set max speed
    float maxSpeed = this.maxSpeed;
    
    //If sliding down a ramp, add force down so player stays grounded and also builds speed
    if (crouching && grounded && readyToJump) {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 3000);
        return;
    }
    
    //If speed is larger than maxspeed, cancel out the input so you don't go over max speed
    if (x > 0 && xMag > maxSpeed) x = 0;
    if (x < 0 && xMag < -maxSpeed) x = 0;
    if (y > 0 && yMag > maxSpeed) y = 0;
    if (y < 0 && yMag < -maxSpeed) y = 0;


    

    //Some multipliers
    float multiplier = 1f, multiplierV = 1f;
    
    // Movement in air
    if (!grounded) {
        maxSpeed = 8f;
    }
    
    // Movement while crouching
    if (grounded && crouching) maxSpeed = 7f;

    //Apply forces to move player
    rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.forward * y * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * multiplier * multiplierV);
    rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.right * x * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * multiplier);
}

private void Jump() {
    if (grounded && readyToJump) {
        readyToJump = false;

        //Add jump forces
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce * 1.5f);
        rb.AddForce(normalVector * jumpForce * 0.5f);
        
        //If jumping while falling, reset y velocity.
        Vector3 vel = rb.velocity;
        if (rb.velocity.y < 0.5f)
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(vel.x, 0, vel.z);
        else if (rb.velocity.y > 0) 
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(vel.x, vel.y / 2, vel.z);
        
        Invoke(nameof(ResetJump), jumpCooldown);
    }
}

private void ResetJump() {
    readyToJump = true;
}

private float desiredX;
private void Look() {
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * sensMultiplier;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * sensMultiplier;

    //Find current look rotation
    Vector3 rot = playerCam.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
    desiredX = rot.y + mouseX;
    
    //Rotate, and also make sure we dont over- or under-rotate.
    xRotation -= mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

    //Perform the rotations
    playerCam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, desiredX, 0);
    orientation.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, desiredX, 0);
}

private void CounterMovement(float x, float y, Vector2 mag) {
    if (!grounded || jumping) return;

    //Slow down sliding
    if (crouching) {
        rb.AddForce(moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * -rb.velocity.normalized * slideCounterMovement);
        return;
    }

    //Counter movement
    if (Math.Abs(mag.x) > threshold && Math.Abs(x) < 0.05f || (mag.x < -threshold && x > 0) || (mag.x > threshold && x < 0)) {
        rb.AddForce(moveSpeed * orientation.transform.right * Time.deltaTime * -mag.x * counterMovement);
    }
    if (Math.Abs(mag.y) > threshold && Math.Abs(y) < 0.05f || (mag.y < -threshold && y > 0) || (mag.y > threshold && y < 0)) {
        rb.AddForce(moveSpeed * orientation.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * -mag.y * counterMovement);
    }
    
    //Limit diagonal running. This will also cause a full stop if sliding fast and un-crouching, so not optimal.
    if (Mathf.Sqrt((Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.z, 2))) > maxSpeed) {
        float fallspeed = rb.velocity.y;
        Vector3 n = rb.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(n.x, fallspeed, n.z);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Find the velocity relative to where the player is looking
/// Useful for vectors calculations regarding movement and limiting movement
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public Vector2 FindVelRelativeToLook() {
    float lookAngle = orientation.transform.eulerAngles.y;
    float moveAngle = Mathf.Atan2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    float u = Mathf.DeltaAngle(lookAngle, moveAngle);
    float v = 90 - u;

    float magnitue = rb.velocity.magnitude;
    float yMag = magnitue * Mathf.Cos(u * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    float xMag = magnitue * Mathf.Cos(v * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    
    return new Vector2(xMag, yMag);
}

private bool IsFloor(Vector3 v) {
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, v);
    return angle < maxSlopeAngle;
}

private bool cancellingGrounded;

/// <summary>
/// Handle ground detection
/// </summary>
private void OnCollisionStay(Collision other) {
    //Make sure we are only checking for walkable layers
    int layer = other.gameObject.layer;
    if (whatIsGround != (whatIsGround | (1 << layer))) return;

    //Iterate through every collision in a physics update
    for (int i = 0; i < other.contactCount; i++) {
        Vector3 normal = other.contacts[i].normal;
        //FLOOR
        if (IsFloor(normal)) {
            grounded = true;
            cancellingGrounded = false;
            normalVector = normal;
            CancelInvoke(nameof(StopGrounded));
        }
    }

    //Invoke ground/wall cancel, since we can't check normals with CollisionExit
    float delay = 3f;
    if (!cancellingGrounded) {
        cancellingGrounded = true;
        Invoke(nameof(StopGrounded), Time.deltaTime * delay);
    }
}

private void StopGrounded() {
    grounded = false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete the return inside this?

```cs
if (crouching && grounded && readyToJump) {
  rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 3000);
  return;
}
```

Because of that, you are not applying force for move your object based on your inputs.